# In PostgreSQL, what is the `index_predicate` for in `INSERT`?

Tags: postgresql, insert, upsert

The [docs on INSERT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-insert.html) say:

> If an `index_predicate` is specified, it must, as a further requirement for inference, satisfy arbiter indexes. Note that this means a non-partial unique index (a unique index without a predicate) will be inferred (and thus used by `ON CONFLICT`) if such an index satisfying every other criteria is available.

I'm not sure I understand this. I **think** it's saying that if I have a non-partial index like this:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON managers (department_id);
```

and I write an insert with `ON CONFLICT (department_id)`, it will infer that it should use the index above.

But if I have a partial index like this:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON managers (department_id) WHERE active = true;
```

then I need to use the `index_predicate` to direct it to use the partial index, like `ON CONFLICT (department_id) WHERE active = true`.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you got it right.

What the documentation is trying to make clear is that if you write `ON CONFLICT (department_id) WHERE active = TRUE`, PostgreSQL can also infer a unique index without a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Ah, thank you! Related question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/332544/in-postgresql-can-an-index-predicate-be-used-to-improve-performance-of-on-conf