# In PostgreSQL, can an index predicate be used to improve performance of `ON CONFLICT`?

Tags: postgresql, upsert

Consider the following upsert, run in a trigger:

```sql
INSERT INTO 
  current_scores (user_id, score, updated_at)
VALUES 
  (NEW.user_id, NEW.score, NEW.inserted_at)
ON CONFLICT (user_id)
DO UPDATE SET
  score = NEW.score,
  updated_at = NEW.inserted_at
WHERE NEW.inserted_at > current_scores.updated_at;
```

It has been suggested to me that duplicating the `WHERE` from the `ON CONFLICT` as an index predicate, like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO 
  current_scores (user_id, score, updated_at)
VALUES 
  (NEW.user_id, NEW.score, NEW.inserted_at)
ON CONFLICT (user_id)

-- added index predicate
WHERE NEW.inserted_at > current_scores.updated_at

DO UPDATE SET
  score = NEW.score,
  updated_at = NEW.inserted_at
WHERE NEW.inserted_at > current_scores.updated_at;
```

...could improve performance by reducing the frequency that `ON CONFLICT` needs to run.
But I don't understand why this might be the case.
If `ON CONFLICT` is expensive, this seems like something the database could figure out on its own.

Can an index predicate be used to reduce conflict resolution and improve performance?

Answer (score 1):

In principle, using a partial index can speed up processing, because it is faster to scan a smaller index. However, I cannot conceive of a partial index that would help in your particular case. Also, the savings will be very small, because looking for a key in a unique index is usually a fast affair.

This strongly smacks of micro-optimization. While a partial index could certainly reduce the execution time a little bit, it will cost you whenever you modify the table. This can easily do more damage than good to your overall performance.